# How to keep my index from reseting in recursiv function in java?

Tags: java, indexing

Im trying to insert my binary tree to an array, there is a recursiv loop in the function, when it re-start my index get reset and im entring the values in the wrong order in the array.
the index is inizilized in the main.

```
public boolean  toArray (Node _root, String[] arr, int i)
{
if (_root == null)
{
return false;
}
if (_root.isleaf())
{
    arr[i]=this.data;
    i++;
    if (this.father == null)
        return false;
    else if (this.father.ls==this)
    {
        this.father.ls = null;
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.father.rs=null;
        return true;
    }
}
    if (_root.ls ==null)
        {
        arr[i] = _root.data;
        i++;
        _root.data=null;
        }
    if ( _root.ls!=null && _root.ls.isleaf() )
    {
        arr[i] = _root.ls.data;
        i++;
        _root.ls = null;
        arr[i]=_root.data;
        i++;

    }
    if ( _root.rs!=null && _root.rs.isleaf())
    {
        arr[i]=_root.rs.data;
        i++;
        _root.rs = null;
    }
    toArray(_root.ls, arr,i);
    toArray(_root.rs, arr,i);
    if (this.data !=null)
        {
        arr[i] = this.data;
        i++;
        this.data = null;
        _root.data=null;
        }
    else 
        return false;
    return false;
}
```

Here is my main class

```
public class Test_Tree {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BT mytree = new BT();
    mytree.in("11","","","");
    mytree.in("2","","","");
    mytree.in("810","","","");
    mytree.in("17","","","");
    mytree.in("845","","","");
    mytree.in("10","","","");
    mytree.in("1","","","");
    String[] arr = new String[10];
    Node myroot = new Node (mytree._root);
    int i=0;
    myroot.toArray(myroot, arr,i);
    for (int j=0; j<arr.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: please format your code correctly and then give example input expected output and actual output for it. Otherwise it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: To add to @Ivaylo - providing something akin to javadoc would help. That is a description of 1. what the method will do, 2. what the inputs are, 3. the return value

Comment: I insert numbers to the binary tree, I axpect to print them in the following order - 1, 2,10,11,17 and co, but my index get reset and the function insert the value 17 in the first cell of the array

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that after executing the first recursive call `toArray(_root.ls, arr,i);`, the value of `i` will not be change, but will remain the same. This is because the integer is passed by value in the recursion and then after the call returns, the local `i` will not have changed. One way to fix the issue is to make the function toArray return an int - the value of `i` when the function returns. It seems you use the boolean return value to indicate if a given subtree is not empty. I believe you will no longer need that.

Code goes something like:

```
public boolean  toArray (Node _root, String[] arr, int i)
{
  if (_root == null)
  {
    return i;
  }
  if (_root.isleaf())
  {
    arr[i]=this.data;
    i++;
    if (this.father == null)
        return i;
    else if (this.father.ls==this)
    {
        this.father.ls = null;
        return i;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.father.rs=null;
        return i;
    }
  }
  if (_root.ls ==null)
  {
    arr[i] = _root.data;
    i++;
    _root.data=null;
  }
  if ( _root.ls!=null && _root.ls.isleaf() )
  {
    arr[i] = _root.ls.data;
    i++;
    _root.ls = null;
    arr[i]=_root.data;
    i++;
  }
  if ( _root.rs!=null && _root.rs.isleaf())
  {
    arr[i]=_root.rs.data;
    i++;
    _root.rs = null;
  }
  i = toArray(_root.ls, arr,i);
  i = toArray(_root.rs, arr,i);
  if (this.data !=null)
  {
    arr[i] = this.data;
    i++;
    this.data = null;
    _root.data=null;
  }
  return i;
}
```